# animate SVG on mouseover

Tags: animation, svg

I need to animate an SVG on mouseover. The idea is that the polygons scatter from the center and come back on mouseout.
I tried using *anime.js*, but I'm not very good with JavaScript at all. Thanks.

```
<svg width="283px" height="193px" viewBox="0 0 283 193" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-299.000000, -582.000000)" stroke="#000000">
            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="550.65 660.48 551.13 661.88 550.93 660.56"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="403.29 705.56 379.49 741.63 405.79 774.14 433.63 774.14 433.63 767.04 410.8 761.88 403.94 743.97 433.63 716.21"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="566.62 753.83 574.52 755.04 581.46 718.01 573.07 703.08 551.37 702.44 528.94 719.14 562.83 719.46 564.6 723.66 557.99 732.61"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="551.13 661.88 550.93 660.56 540.77 591.5 504.98 582.55 466.9 617.73 466.57 619.09 558.54 684.86 558.87 684.36 551.39 662.63"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="529.42 774.14 562.63 774.14 562.63 767.68 537.13 760.26 531.38 741.41 496.83 733.18"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="453.36 718.6 455.03 650.1 376.54 655.09 406.3 703.27"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="485.01 718.78 492.75 728.51 529.99 737.39 524.34 718.89 548.06 700.5 556.31 688.19 522.22 663.81"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="565.17 664.19 574.2 648.38 566.62 636.28 566.94 625.47 559.68 614.34 562.42 608.04 545.26 594.5 555.14 661.63"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="481.13 717.36 518.96 661.48 465.56 623.29 459.16 649.83 459.04 649.84 457.34 719.64"></polygon>

            <polygon id="poly" fill="#2D2D2D" points="316.04 749.29 328.46 774.14 357.67 774.14 356.86 766.72 339.44 763.33 334.27 752.84 342.95 740.58 325.32 724.5"></polygon>

            <path id="path" fill="#2D2D2D" d="M343.79,690 L357.35,676.78 L344.44,712.92 L328.18,722.11 L347,739.31 L370.54,732.93 L401.66,703.44 L373,657 L359.93,667.26 C359.93,667.26 340.16,685.65 336.53,687.59 C332.9,689.53 319.83,692 319.83,692 L306.52,684.44 L306.93,669.9 L322.49,656.61 L314.26,654.43 L303.86,658.31 L300.47,685.41 L321.28,699.69 L343.79,690 Z"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail on what you tried that didn't work?  Also, I would add the javascript tag to your question as that is where your problem seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its pretty simple to do. I don't know if you want it in javascript but im a fan of doing this with css:

```
    polygon:hover{
animation: animation 2s linear;
}
```

then you have to make your keyframe to animate the polygon.

```
@keyframes animation{
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(10deg);   
  }
}
```

all it takes for you to do now is to give each polygon a different id and animate them with different keyframes. What i showed above is just an example on how it animating works so its up to you on what you exactly want to do with it.

If you have any other questions feel free to ask!

Comment: If it did (or didn't) help please let me know!